# Disable caching in custom views in Flask Admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I want to disable cahce in `Flask-Admin` panel, where i displaying some images. For exmaple, i have 1 image in my DB (actually, just uri to an image). If i delete this image, and then upload a new one, the cache will show me deleted image.
To escape this moment, i need disable caching. But, also, i want disable it on all `Flask-Admin` pages.

```
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}

{% block head_meta %}
{{super()}}
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
{% endblock head_meta %}
```

I know if i save code above as index.html, it applies only to index admin page panel.
But, as i also said above, i want to disable caching on all pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some information about it. If you want to edit your **CUSTOM** view, you should add these variables:

```
list_template = 'list.html'
create_template = 'create.html'
edit_template = 'edit.html'
```

Where `list.html` responsible for list with all your records and so on.

Also, you should create template, where you put all your code to append to existing `Flask-Admin`. In my case, it looks like this:

```
{% extends 'admin/model/list.html' %}

    {% block head_meta %}
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
        {{ super() }}
    {% endblock head_meta %}
```

above is example of disabling cache on page where all records are show